# Prove the inequality $\frac{ab}c+\frac{ac}b+\frac{bc}a\ge a^2+b^2+c^2-abc+1$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c \in [10;100]$. Prove the inequality
> $$\frac{ab}c+\frac{ac}b+\frac{bc}a\ge a^2+b^2+c^2-abc+1$$

#### My work so far:

$$\frac{ab}c+\frac{ac}b+\frac{bc}a\ge a^2+b^2+c^2-abc+1 \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (ab-c)(ac-b)(bc-a)\ge0$$

Comment: Hint: Observe that $ab\geq c$ when $a,b,c\in[10,100]$.

Comment: @SomuSaiteja: Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the inequality you give, it remains to show that $ab\geq c$, which follows from the fact that $a,b,c\in [10,100]$:
$$ab\geq 10\cdot 10=100\geq c.$$

Answer (score 1):

$ab-c\geq0$, $ac-b\geq0$, $bc-a\geq0$. Done!